# are external http requests detrimental?

Tags: performance, html, http, httpwebrequest

I'm using a service to generate code and i get responses back from an external service. I'm often getting 30+ at a time.

I'm also using a favicon service to fetch favicons. The favicon service allows prefixing the domain with an arbitrary number to bypass the browser connection limit (eg. http://2245.example.com/?url=example.net)

In total my site can make upwards of 50-100 requests, but 15 of them are from my server
I used yslow and got a big fat F for this. Are these requests blocking? I could be generating 30 or more on a single page load, although it seems to load fine in testing... everything on my actual page loads immediately and I use css3 and jquery to fade in the animations nicely

Comment: Are the requests being launched asynchronously after the page has fully loaded?

Comment: im not sure. they are an image tags with href="" pointing to the external website. I do have 2 external scripts which are for ajax-google-jquery and google-fonts

Comment: Then yes tha will get you the bad yslow grade. You have numerous external image links to non static media. They are loading with your normal page load. Maybe yslow sees that they dont cache well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a maximum of 4-6 concurrent requests in most browsers so the others will be delayed yes, but it depends on what they are as to whether or not they're blocking.

You should avoid it - if it's part of your service consider loading the data in bulk on your server for the client via an AJAX call, that way you can also cache the results to avoid so many offsite requests.

It'd help if you could show the page for more comprehensive advice, what're the codes for? Do they change? Can you do it from your server rather than the client?

Comment: They are all image tags. I do have 2 scripts which load jquery from google, and an @font-face file from google, but aside from those 2 scripts theyre all images. i was considering using reverse proxy once i get my app deployed, but to be honest i really like the 'organic' loading look of the images, as they all fade in out of order when they're ready... it started out as a 'bug' and now its a feature :) it looks very cool like that, id rather not have them fade all in at once

Comment: Are they user images or can they be sprited? Lots of external resources sometimes cannot be avoided in terms of avatars and such - you can increase your page score by spreading them across multiple sub domains as it'll increase the amount you can concurrently load, you can setup more agressive caching and there is also no need for session cookies to be transmitted which each request.

Comment: They are thumbnails for websites, so they can't be sprited. Its url2png.com

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have a pipeline where a limited number of requests are simultaneously executed so there will be a bottleneck if your web page is loading 50-100+ images.

The best way to get around this is to serve up image content as sprites. This involves:

- Getting your server to fetch the images on behalf of the web page.
- Creating the corresponding sprites on the server side.
- Serving up the sprited images as well as the sprite decoding reference points to the web page from your server.